# Batch - read array

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I have a problem witch .bat file
I have somethis like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set arr[a]=1
set arr[b]=2

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (somefile.txt) do (
set key=a
echo /!key!/ /!arr[%key%]!/
)
```

And code above not work correctly. I mean that the key is display correct but value of !arr[%key%]! is empty (i don't know why).

When i try it like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set arr[a]=1
set arr[b]=2

set key=a

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (somefile.txt) do (
echo /!key!/ /!arr[%key%]!/
)
```

Code above work good. No idea why first code doesn't work and second work. Any ideas ?

Comment: See: [Arrays and other data structures in Batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set arr[a]=1
set arr[b]=2

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (q27861004.txt) do (
 set key=%%a
 echo /!key!/ /!arr[%%a]!/
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27861004.txt` containing this data for my testing.

```
a
b
```

Your problem is that `%kay%` is evaluated at parse-time, replacing `%key%` with its value at that time, being *empty*, hence displaying `!arr[]!` also *empty*